# Hangfire how to write crontab if there is a Start Date and End Date?

Tags: cron, hangfire

I understand that crontab expression doesn't have the 'Year' expression. But I would like to know, if there is a workaround or something which can enable the Hangfire to start/stop scheduling at a specified Year.

For example, given a case:

- Assume current date is 2016, September 15
- Scheduler Starts on 2016, December, 1
- Repeat every hour from 8.30am till 5.30pm daily (office hour)
- Happens on weekday Monday-Friday
- End on 2018, Februrary, 1

Understood from other post that, it may require more than 1 crontab expression in some cases. But for this one, i have no idea how to write. Reason:

if i write:

- "30 8 1 12 0-4": it only specifies December 1
- "30 8 * * 0-4": it doesn't tell which month to start or end

How to write this crontab?

Comment: After posting this, i am thinking maybe the Start Date could be possibly handled by using 'Delayed Tasked' with a specified date. In the delayed task, introduce the recurring task...
Meanwhile, the End Date (year info) is stored in another column which, everytime when the task is run, the year is retrieved to see if it is still within the current year info... if it doesn't, then remove the job...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure of a clean way. But it could be handled in this manner-
5 jobs:

2 Delayed Jobs to run on Start Date and End Date(StartDateDelayedJob, EndDateDelayedJob)

3 Recurring Jobs -

1. 1st with cron expression (* */1 * * 1-5) to run the expected task every hour from monday to friday,
2. 2nd with cron expression (30 8 * * 1-5) to add the 1st recurrence job every day at 8 30 if it is monday to friday,
3. 3rd with cron expression of (30 17 * * 1-5) to remove the 1st recurring job every day at 5 30 if it is monday to friday.

StartDateDelayedJob will add 2nd Recurrence Job and 3rd Recurrence Job.

EndDateDelayedJob will remove the two Recurrence Jobs.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am thinking, maybe this can be enhanced to only 3 jobs?
First: One delayed job to run on Start Date.
Second: That job from (1) is to run a recurring job of expression (30 8-17 * * 1-5)
Third: One delayed job to run on End Date. That job is to remove the recurring jobs from (2)

Comment: Do you mind changing to only 5 jobs? I will accept that as the answer. (if you agree with me)

Comment: The answer above already has five jobs . Could you please explain what do you want me change or agree to? thanks in advance

Comment: The expression (30 8-17/1 * * 1-5) could be replacing your 1), 2), 3) is it? Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Yes. It sure will. Good find. Didnot realise i could join the three cron expressions

Comment: Yup. It was my typo at Jan 9. In the end, it is 3 jobs. Thanks.